# How can I write the following propositional logic in symbol format?

Tags: logic, computer-science, logic-translation

Considering the proposition:

Neither person has cups, unless they have fridges

Considering:

person has cups -> p

have fridges -> q

How could I write this in the correct way?

Thanks

Comment: The word *neither* in English has a connotation of "not either" of two alternatives.  So to capture the notion that exactly two persons are involved, more symbols are needed.  Such additional meaning seems outside the scope of a *propositional logic* exercise, so it is a little puzzling how you are expected to proceed.  Were you told to use just the propositions $p,q$ you identified, or was this part of your own thinking?

Comment: "person has cups" isn't really a sentence. I mean, does that mean "a person has cups", or "all persons have cups"? "have fridges" is even more obscure. And even the whole sentence "Neither person has cups, unless they have fridges" is a little weird ... is that supposed to be "No person has cups, unless they have a fridge"? Your $p$ and $q$ seem like predicates more than propositions. Are you currently studying propositional logic or predicate logic?

Comment: With prop logic you can easily manage a *finite* number of cases. Consider for example two individual Peter and John. We symbolize "Peter has cups" with $Pc$ and with $Jc$ the similar for John. And we use $Pf$ for "Peter has fridges" and the same with $Pf$.

Comment: Now, for "Neither person has cups" becomes $\lnot Pc \land \lnot Jc$.

Comment: Do you think the phrase "unless they have fridges" means *both* people have to have fridges in order for either of them to have cups? Or do you think it means just that a person must have a fridge in order to have a cup?

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear on the sentence (because english is also not my first language), but the most suitable sentence for this case would be "No person has cups, unless they have a fridge", as pointed out by Bram28.

As for the questions:

hardmath - It's actually part of an exercise I'm doing, and I just used different sentences.

Bram28 - I'm studying both

As for the answers, thanks a lot for the response! Didn't actually expected to get so many answers this fast.

Comment: Adrian, for your question, it`s the second case you pointed out.

Comment: Adding to my comment, what would be the equivalent ways to write the sentence "No person has cups, unless they have a fridge", and also "No person that has cups has fridges"?

Answer (score 0):

Using your notation: $P(x)$ is defined as "$x$ has cups", and $Q(x)$ is defined as "$x$ has fridges". Then you could write it like this:
$$(\forall\,x)(P(x)\implies Q(x)).$$

Answer (score 0):

Using $P(x)$ for "$x$ has cups" and $Q(x)$ for "$x$ has a fridge".

> Adding to my comment, what would be the equivalent ways to write the sentence "No person has cups, unless they have a fridge", and also "No person that has cups has fridges"?

- "No person that has cups, does not have a fridge." $\neg\exists x~(P(x)\wedge \neg Q(x))$
- "Any person will have a fridge if they have cups." $\forall x~(P(x)\to Q(x))$
- "Any person will not have cups if they do not have a fridge." $\forall x~(\neg Q(x)\to \neg P(x))$